# WebRTC Example Not Connecting

Tags: javascript, webrtc

So I'm starting a project using RTCDataChannels to transport text. I thought I understood how it worked, but after writing a bunch of code, I thought maybe not, so I simplified it down to the most basic example, and I still can't get these two sockets to connect.

I was under the understanding that once two sockets have their local and remote descriptions set correctly, and their ice candidates are being passed to eachother, then they will just connect automatically. The example code creates two RTCPeerConnections, and sets them up as explained to connect to eachother, but their status implies there is still work to do.

I'm probably missing something, like the order is wrong, or I'm missing a step somewhere. Most of the code is taken from this [MDN Example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Simple_RTCDataChannel_sample), so maybe that's out of date?

Any help would be appreciated, and it's my first question so please say if you need more information or if there are any problems. Thanks.

```html
<div id="log"></div>
<script>
var cfg = {'iceServers': [{'url': 'stun:23.21.150.121'}]},
  con = { 'optional': [{'DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement': true}] }


var client = new RTCPeerConnection(cfg, con);
var host = new RTCPeerConnection(cfg, con);

host.onicecandidate = function(can){client.addIceCandidate(can.candidate || can)}
client.onicecandidate = function(can){host.addIceCandidate(can.candidate || can)}

host.createOffer()
    .then(offer => host.setLocalDescription(offer))
    .then(() => client.setRemoteDescription(host.localDescription))
    .then(() => client.createAnswer())
    .then(answer => client.setLocalDescription(answer))
    .then(() => host.setRemoteDescription(client.localDescription))
    .then(function(){
   log(host.iceConnectionState);
   log(client.iceConnectionState);
    });

var log = msg => document.querySelector("#log").innerHTML += "<br>" + msg;
</script>
```